Run Flutter widget test option is not visible in Android Studio
I have an issue with Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1 and cannot find anywhere why it happens.
As you can see in the screenshot, I have the run Flutter widget test options on the main method but not on the individual tests. Why ?

Also, rerunning the failed tests runs all the tests again. This is kind of annoying since I know this worked before.


I also reported a bug for Android Studio:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/353294042

It seems it is a Flutter plugin issue so I created a new ticket there:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/7568

This was fixed in flutter-intellij plugin: https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/7568
